# 4 Wide Columns in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I apologize for the dumb question, but really don't want to send this to my devs. I am trying to add a fourth column to this area for another automotive brand. I tried duplicating one of the lists -- and it placed it on a separate line. Looking to go four wide.

[Here is what is looks like live with three-wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW3CQ.png).

```html
<h2>Most popular selections:</h2>
    <ul class="col-wrapper">
        <li class="col-outer">
            <ul class="col-inner-wrapper">
                <li class="col-inner col-title"><h3>Volkswagen</h3></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--Golf-GTI-Rabbit--MK7--2015--2.0T">MK7 GTI 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--.-R-Models--MK7-R--2015--2.0T">MK7 Golf R 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--Golf-GTI-Rabbit--MK6--10-2014--2.0T">MK6 GTI 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--.-R-Models--MK6-R--2012-2013--2.0T-FSI">MK6 Golf R 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--CC--2009--2.0-TSI">CC 2.0 TSI</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--.-R-Models--MK5-R32--2008--VR6-3.2L">MK5 R32 3.2L</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-outer">
            <ul class="col-inner-wrapper">
                <li class="col-inner col-title"><h3>Audi</h3></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--S3--2015--2.0T">S3 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--A4--B7--05.5-2008--2.0T-FSI--Quattro">A4 2.0 FSI Quattro</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--S4--B5--00-2002--2.7T">S4 2.7T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--A4--B6--02-2005--1.8T--Quattro">A4 1.8T Quattro</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--A3--8P--05-2013--2.0T-FSI">A3 2.0T FSI</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--S5--B8--2008-2012--V8-4.2L">S5 4.2L</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-outer">
            <ul class="col-inner-wrapper">
                <li class="col-inner col-title"><h3>Porsche</h3></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Porsche--911-Turbo--997.2--10-2012--3.8TT">911 Turbo 997.2 3.8TT</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Porsche--911-Turbo--997.1--07-2009--3.6TT">911 Turbo 997.1 3.6TT</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Porsche--911-Turbo--996--01-2005--3.6TT">911 Turbo 996 3.6TT </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Adding another `<li class="col-outer">` (with content) should do the trick, but without seeing the CSS we can't be sure it will display correctly.

Comment: You'd need to share your CSS with us as well.

Comment: I appreciate the response -- tried adding a <li class="col-outer"> placed it on a second line.

Comment: "really don't want to send this to my devs" SO is not a free code-writing service. You need to review [ask] and include a [mcve] to show that you've invested some time into solving your own problem.

Comment: Understood, not the best thing for my first post. I can include the addition of the fourth column being bumped down, but I figured due to the simplicity. It would be understood.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .col-outer { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

```html
 <ul class="col-wrapper">
        <li class="col-outer">
            <ul class="col-inner-wrapper">
                <li class="col-inner col-title"><h3>Volkswagen</h3></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--Golf-GTI-Rabbit--MK7--2015--2.0T">MK7 GTI 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--.-R-Models--MK7-R--2015--2.0T">MK7 Golf R 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--Golf-GTI-Rabbit--MK6--10-2014--2.0T">MK6 GTI 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--.-R-Models--MK6-R--2012-2013--2.0T-FSI">MK6 Golf R 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--CC--2009--2.0-TSI">CC 2.0 TSI</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Volkswagen--.-R-Models--MK5-R32--2008--VR6-3.2L">MK5 R32 3.2L</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-outer">
            <ul class="col-inner-wrapper">
                <li class="col-inner col-title"><h3>Audi</h3></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--S3--2015--2.0T">S3 2.0T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--A4--B7--05.5-2008--2.0T-FSI--Quattro">A4 2.0 FSI Quattro</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--S4--B5--00-2002--2.7T">S4 2.7T</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--A4--B6--02-2005--1.8T--Quattro">A4 1.8T Quattro</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--A3--8P--05-2013--2.0T-FSI">A3 2.0T FSI</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Audi--S5--B8--2008-2012--V8-4.2L">S5 4.2L</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="col-outer">
            <ul class="col-inner-wrapper">
                <li class="col-inner col-title"><h3>Porsche</h3></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Porsche--911-Turbo--997.2--10-2012--3.8TT">911 Turbo 997.2 3.8TT</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Porsche--911-Turbo--997.1--07-2009--3.6TT">911 Turbo 997.1 3.6TT</a></li>
                <li class="col-inner"><a href="{$current_location}/Porsche--911-Turbo--996--01-2005--3.6TT">911 Turbo 996 3.6TT </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        
    </ul>
```

Comment: How does this differ from the code I pasted? The addition of the CSS rule?

Comment: Yes please add this css line 
 .col-outer { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}